# Why is the version of Vim displayed by 'apt' different from the one displayed in Vim?

Tags: version

These the output of the commands to check which version of Vim I am using on Devain Jessie and Debian Sid

I have checked my systems -

**Output of debian jessie**

```
:python import sys; print(sys.version)

2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:11:10)
[GCC 4.9.2]

   VIM - Vi IMproved    

    version 7.4.576     
by Bram Moolenaar et al.

apt-cache policy vim

vim:                                                                      
  Installed: 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u2                                           
  Candidate: 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u2                                           
  Version table:                                                          
 *** 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u2 0                                                 
        500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status                                          
     2:7.4.488-7+deb8u1 0                                                 
        500 http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

**Output of debian sid**

```
:python import sys; print(sys.version)

E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version

apt-cache policy vim

vim:
  Installed: 2:8.0.0197-3
  Candidate: 2:8.0.0197-4
  Version table:
     2:8.0.0197-4 500
        500 http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2:8.0.0197-3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

start up screen

```
VIM - Vi IMproved   

 version 8.0.378    
by Bram Moolenaar et al.
```

Why does the `apt-cache` policy output usually different from the version reported by Vim?

Is there a version Vim already built into Vim 8, or does it require an additional build with python?

Comment: why the downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in `/usr/share/doc/vim/NEWS.Debian.gz`, the Debian packages have switched to building against Python3 for Stretch.  If you upgraded a system to Stretch and didn't see this message, then I highly recommend installing the `apt-listchanges` package, so you are informed of important changes like this in the future.

If you notice, when you ran `:python` it said `E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version`.

Your command would need to change to

```
:python3 import sys; print(sys.version)
```

Also, the `vim` package itself doesn't have any of the language bindings enabled.  You need either `vim-nox` or one of the packages providing `gvim`.

As far as why `:intro` shows a larger version than the package version, I had backported some upstream patches to fix various bugs before Jessie was released.  You'll see these if you run `:version`.  The version reported by `:intro` is just the highest patch number that's been included.

Comment: I asked this question in another forum because installing all of `YouCompleteMe` was causing `vim` to start slowly. It starts quickly now after installing `vim-nox`. Does installing `vim-nox` require `YouCompleteMe` to be recompiled or should it work transparently?

Comment: After applying installing `vim-nox` running `:python3 import sys; print(sys.version)` results in  


3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)

[GCC 6.3.0 20170118]